# How to display 2 list values with the same index from dictionary variable in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

everyone! I have a problem with my python code. I have 2 values list of a dictionary, here's the example code:

```
stocks = {"product":["iphone", "xiaomi", "samsung"], "amount":[10, 21, 17]}
```

What should I do if I want to print "Product name: iphone, amount: 10" which is each value (element of list) has the same index. I hope somebody could solve it as soon as possible. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use `zip()`!
Example:

```
result = zip(stocks["product"], stocks["amount"])
```

Using `zip()` returns a `zip` object, which we can then iterate through like this:

```
for item in result:
     print(item[0], "costs:", item[1])
```

Output:

```
xiaomi costs: 21
iphone costs: 10
samsung costs: 17
```

Comment: There's no reason to use a set here.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Wrote it out of being used to it. Edited to remove.

Comment: can you explain why it should use zip function? because i just started learn python hehe and thank you it works, btw

Comment: `zip()` receives arguments which are iterables, meaning that they can be looped through. So because both of the values in your dictionary are lists, they are iterables and therefore can be passed to the `zip()` function. What `zip()` does is take your iterables, and returns one single iterable object, with each value being a tuple, where each index in the returned iterable is the tuple built of the values in the same index in the parameter iterables.

Comment: So because you wanted to match the name of the phone to the price, and the correspondence is by the index within the lists, `zip()` came to mind. You can read more here: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip

Comment: No problem. I'd appreciate it if you could accept this answer :)